# Applying folder attributes in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, attributes, directory, explorer

In Windows explorer detail view, I can add various columns to the view to display meta data, covering many many different attributes (Title, Description, Author, Categories, Tags etc).

For files, I can then open the properties tab for the file in question, go to details, and add or change properties for the file. Those properties are then displayed in Windows explorer in the relevant column.

For folders, you would assume this works in the same way, but it doesn't.

I really want to be able to add a bit of 'description' text to folders in Windows, that displays in the relevant column in Windows explorer. Does anyone know a simple way to achieve this?

For a bit of context, this is to add some recoverability to a project filing system I've built, whereby if the main database application is compromised, the files can be navigable manually via Windows explorer.

So, for example, my project folders are named:

A0001

A0002

A0003 ...and so on.

And what I'd really like would be a separate column that I can sort / order by:

A0001 ... Bills & Invoices

A0002 ... Receipts & Bank Statements

A0003 ... Purchase Orders

A0004 ... Misc Quotes

Windows Explorer is so close to being able to do this (it does it for files), that I suspect there *must* be a way?

Comment: Although according to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) questions relating to "software tools commonly used by programmers" -- which certainly include Windows Explorer -- are on-topic here, I feel that your question will get better/quicker answers on [Super User](http://superuser.com) . However please don't cross-post it there unless you delete this one as moderators can move the question there.

Comment: What you need to do is write a custom property handler for folders.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I assume through my database system (I've written that in Access 2010 / VBA).